Как исправить ошибку: Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Text?
Текс ошибки:
Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Text of type LiveChartsCore:LiveChartsCore.VisualElements.LabelVisual`2 for argument Avalonia.Markup.Xaml:Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.CompiledBindingExtension, available setter parameter lists are:System.String Line 46, position 62.
LineSmoothness.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="200"
         x:Class="AvaloniaApplication1.Views.LineSmoothness"
         x:DataType="vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness"
         xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView"
         xmlns:ve="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.VisualElements"
         xmlns:lvca="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia"
         xmlns:lvcp="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Painting"
         xmlns:lvK="using:LiveChartsCore.Kernel"
         xmlns:vms="using:AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Design.DataContext>
    <vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness/>
</Design.DataContext>
<lvca:CartesianChart Name="ChartLine">
    <lvca:CartesianChart.VisualElements>
        <ve:LabelVisual TextSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding TextMarker}"/>
    </lvca:CartesianChart.VisualElements>
</lvca:CartesianChart>

ViewModelLineSmoothness.cs
internal partial class ViewModelLineSmoothness : ObservableObject, IItemViewModel
{
  public string TextMarker { get; set; }

  public ViewModelLineSmoothness()
  {
  }
}


Версия библиотеки LiveChartsCore какая? Если прсто текст туда прописать вместо бинда, ошибка уйдёт или нет?

Да, просто с текстом работать будет. LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia 2.0.0-rc2
